# Property of @IdClass not found in entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I use spring boot 2, jpa and hibernate

with this code

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Samplings {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "samplings_id_seq", strategy="com.lcm.model.SamplingSequenceGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "samplings_id_seq")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sampling")
    private List<Samples> samples = new ArrayList<>();

}   

@Entity
@IdClass(SamplesPK.class)
public class Samples  {

    @Id
    private String sampleLetter;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private Samplings sampling;
}   

public class SamplesPK implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;

    private String sampleLetter;

    public SamplesPK(Integer id, String sampleLetter) {
        this.id = id;
        this.sampleLetter = sampleLetter;
    }

    .... //get / set
}
```

I get this error:

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Property of @IdClass not found in entity com.lcm.model.Samples:: id

Comment: SamplesPK has "id", and Samples doesn't. And ?

Answer (score 11):

The names of the fields or properties in the primary key class and the primary key fields or properties of the entity must correspond and their types must be the same. From docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/IdClass.html).

Your `Samples` class should have its id as the same type of your `SamplesPK`.

You should have a `@Id private Integer id` in your `Samples` class

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you miss some components of your SamplesPk.class in your Samples entity.

It is called Samples:: **samplingId**

Here you have an example [LINK](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/01/jpa-idclass-example/)

EDIT:

So your entity should look like this :

```
@Entity
@IdClass(SamplesPK.class)
public class Samples  {

    @Id
    private String sampleLetter;

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "sampling_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private Samplings sampling;
}
```

Comment: in fact not working because id hibernate don't feed id field